# Plotting trajectory of an aircraft with orientation information

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Given the orientation history of an aircraft (in addition to the position history), is there a way to generate a 3d trajectory plot where the orientation information is also provided in the same plot? For example, by using a custom marker (aircraft picture) to represent the orientation of the aircraft at any point on the trajectory? Please see the attached figure for reference. TIA

[image]

Comment: Well, as with all problems, you should start by simpler things. Are you able to draw the trajectory? Then, are you able to add a single plane image to that plot? Then, are you able to add a rotated version of the image? This question needs a [Minimal, reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Matlab tool that does this.

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4572-trajectory-and-attitude-plot-version-2